# Laravel changing of primaryKey don't work

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to change the primaryKey of my Model in Laravel. The primaryKey is already set in Database, and in the Model, but both doesn't work.

I get this error message:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `` = 123456 limit 1)

When I unset the primaryKey within the Model, I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`id` = 123456 limit 1)

Which is totally legit, because the primaryKey should be set to 'vid' within the Model.

Here is the essential part of my Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Model implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'vid' => 'string'
    ];

    protected $table = 'users';
    protected $primaryKey = 'vid';
    public $incrementing = false;

}
```

Migration:

```
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('vid');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('surname');
            $table->integer('val1');
            $table->integer('val2');
            $table->integer('val3');
            $table->string('val4');
            $table->string('val5');
            $table->integer('val6');
            $table->integer('val7');
            $table->integer('val8');
            $table->dateTime('val9');
            $table->string('val10');
            $table->string('val11');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: Try adding `protected $keyType = 'string';` to your user model.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Didn't work, same error `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from users where `` = 123456 limit 1)`

Comment: Maybe try removing the casts property. It might be conflicting somewhere, not entirely sure though.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Still the same error, even with removing it

Comment: Can you include your user table migration?

Comment: @DigitalDrifter It's edited

Comment: Try removing the chained call to `primary()` in your migration so it's just `$table->string('vid');`. You'll need to manually remove the index from the user's table or rerun your migrations.

Comment: @DigitalDrifter Same error as ever after new migration.

Comment: Dang, I dont know what else to try at this point. I've never ran into issues when setting a pk like you are now. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't tell you what was wrong, but remaking the User Model helped.